# Apache Tika - Paragraph Breaks in .doc files

Tags: apache-tika

Right now I am testing full text extraction using Apache Tika.
I use the facade class Tika with pretty much default configuration. 
The problem lies in the way Tika processes paragraph breaks.

I created few test files in different formats - docx, pdf, plain text, odt, rtf, doc containing exactly same content. For all of these formats, except for doc, the paragraphs are either separated with '\n\n' or '\r\n'.

For example, instead of getting:

> paragraph1\n\nparagraph2

I get:

> paragraph1paragraph2

Is there a way to configure Tika in a way, that makes it preserve the paragraph breaks in doc files, in the same way it does for other file types?

Comment: What version of Apache Tika are you using? And if you fetch as XHTML rather than plain text, do the paragraphs have the right markup separating them?

Comment: @Gagravarr Tika's version: 1.17. When I output content in xhtml, then for example for txt file I get something like this: "<p>para1\r\npara2</p>" and for doc: "<p>para1</p><p>para2</p>". So it looks like it detects the paragraphs for docs just fine, but it doesn't concatenate them with newlines when outputing the String in parseToString.